# How to get the exact value list result using loop

Tags: c#, loops

this is my database which lists 5 results of the menu,

[image]

what i want is, if the date not equal to current Date (`DateTime.Now`), the result will be zero, like this:

[image]

Here is my code, on what I'm trying to do,

```
for (int i = 1; i <= DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Length; i++)

            if (list.Any(x => x.Date.ToShortDateString() == i.ToString() ))
        {
            list.ToList().Add(new MenuModel
            {
                Total = list.First(x => x.Date.ToShortDateString() == i.ToString()).Total,
                Location = list.First(x => x.Date.ToShortDateString() == i.ToString()).Location,

            });
        }
        else
        {
            list.Add(new MenuModel
            {
                Total = list.First(x => x.Date.ToShortDateString() != i.ToString()).Total=0,
                Location = list.First(x => x.Date.ToShortDateString() != i.ToString()).Location,

            });

        }
```

but the result that i get is like this,

[image]

The location, didnt show the real value, which will be A,B,C,D and E.. How to get the exact value of location?

Comment: `x.Date.ToShortDateString() == i.ToString()`  Please explain what that you think that code is achieving (since it is **very odd**).

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Length; i++)` Please explain what that you think that code is achieving (since it is **very odd**).

Comment: This code contains a lot of mistakes, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really need is little `linq` magic. The below linq Get the `Total` based on the current date to actual value and if not to current date then set to 0.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
var menus = list.Select(l => new MenuModel
            {
                Total = l.Date.Date == date ? l.Total : 0,
                Location = l.Location,
            });
```